overriding objects of generic types
Consider the following code, where I'm trying to override and also specify the parameter passed to a generic class method:
   class MyBaseClass {
       getData<T extends MyBaseClass>(classes: {[key: string]: T}){}
    }
    
    
    class FirstChild extends MyBaseClass {
       private data: number[];
    
       constructor(){ data = [//get data]}
    }
    
    // e.g. 1
    class SecondChild extends MyBaseClass {
         private data: number[];

         getData<FirstChild>(classes: {category: FirstChild}){} // error
    }

now, this gives an error and for it to be error free, I'm gonna have to change SecondChild to:
  class SecondChild extends MyBaseClass {
             getData(classes: {[key: string]: FirstChild}){} // error
        }

I'm wondering if something similar to my first example (e.g.1) is possible. What I want is to generalize the base class but, specify the elements that I pass to the child class.
For example, if it were possible I could get specific keys for extended entities while not worrying about them in parent. E.g. 2:
class ThirdChild extends MyBaseClass {
         getData(classes: {category1: FirstChild, category2: SecondChild}){
            const categoryAData = category1.getData(),
            const categoryBData = category2.getData(),

       } 
    }

Is there a way to somehow achieve this?

"What I want is to generalize the base class" - why? Can you show what such a generic call to getData would look like? Is MyBaseClass abstract or does MyBaseClass.getData have an actual implementation as well?

You're probably looking for class MyBaseClass<T extends {[key: string]: MyBaseClass<{}>}> { getData(classes: T){} }

@Bergi, a call would look like:
thirdChildInstance.getData({category1: instanceOfCat1, category2: instanceOfCat2}), where all of categoryN are subclasses of MyBaseClass

@Bergi , in your second comment, what does the <{}> in class MyBaseClass<T extends {[key: string]: MyBaseClass<{}>}> { getData(classes: T){} } denote? is it similar to any used by David in his answer?

I wasn't sure what to write there. {}, unknown, never, Record<string, unkown>, Record<string, never>? It'll need to allow all T that somehow are a record of some MyBaseClasses, but at the same time it needs to fulfill that type requirement itself. any always works but I try to avoid it where I can.

I had to fix up your example quite a bit to get it to compile, but this captures what I understand you to be trying to do -- specializing the type of the properties to the argument to getData() in a way that's consistent throughout the class.
Here's a playground link.
class MyBaseClass<D extends MyBaseClass<D> = MyBaseClass<any>> {
  getData(classes: {[key: string]: D}): number[] {
    return [];
  }
}

class FirstChild extends MyBaseClass {
  private data: number[];
    
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.data = this.getData({});
  }
}
    
class SecondChild extends MyBaseClass<FirstChild> {
  getData(classes: {category: FirstChild}){
    return [];
  }
}


the ? in the D extends... is for some reason giving me a JSDoc types can only be used inside documentation comments. in vscode

I altered it slightly in a way that I think will get around that.

I add a key/value pair in the object to the code above, it gives me an error: playground:  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeAhSBTAwuKAeAItFAHgC4oB2AJjAshOphLgHzQC8cSqGkDYp8jzAN4AoaNADmKIjjBEwAClDcUEAFzRBAbQDWKeOohEATgEtS4gLrqcAXwCU60gFcAtgCMURzRY2ix0IyknI1JobwBuPxthaOElKGgAMRMjQzQACxMQcnxiMkp2GjpuXzEAB1MAN1kUaHJZMEdXDy8LSP9oP2AAe1JDIydgIm6jeTtS-wgnMs8x9v8iTIgAOnq5VmhFkxXJaQb5QXt56OiOuPpoAGUUHooMrJzCEgoqDloubGTUonvsoT9djI5Ip6Cp1IJgDVxCN9EkUmlMtl7CIOoEiMFQhEojFhOcSgAVTJGci-R55F6FTj0LBfBEPf5iQH7eK0NQaSEkaFGWG0n6I8gAGmgHJQXPgACZ1NdbiT+ci-GI0Riwm1sdEgA

but, based on comment and your code above, this seems to work: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeAhSBTAwuKAeaAJaKAHgC4oB2AJjAN7QDaA1ivAFzQTEBOAlmQOYBdNgmQR0mCFmoBfAHzQ50aNQBQSvimIARMMTAAKUJDEQ21RszYce-IXmkBKNmQCuAWwBGKTnQHK1StCcmi6cZPQCANwB0iqxKkZQ0ABi3JwcaAAW3CAUBCTkVHBIqBjGUoqqSgAOPABuuijQFLpgzu5ePlEBSgHAAPZk1i7AxP2c+g7+gewu1d6T0TPE2RAAdC160AC80Cvc6xrarfoyDksKcT3QCRLQAMooA5RZOXlEpJQwIqUSFfJVaBHHR6QwSFCmZTARp8casFJpDLZXKOQFKYLEULhXwXWLxRIwAAq2U4FFeuXynyKPzEZWwMgBAWBJwJELM0NIsM48NS6WI5IoABpoByUFz4AAmNiPZ5k5EUVHXDFYiK4q5AA

I don't fully understand the use of the empty object in MyBaseClass<{}> , but it gives me the desired behaviour

hm... it appears my solution was also not quite working, I believe it worked like 'any' syntax, since it appears I can pass any data there now when I wanted to constrain to only values child of the base class

I'll go ahead and replace the code in my answer with yours

Actually, I'll leave it as is for now -- the second playground above doesn't really constrain the argument types in the same way as my original answer. I can play with it a little more, starting with your first playground.
